# CSS/Javascript Auto Scroll To Top

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am currently working on a simple (or so I thought) slide-down menu for both the desktop and mobile versions of a website I am working on. I'm trying to do this in CSS only if possible. Currently the CSS I am using is as follows:

```
#menu {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; max-height: 50px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: all 1s ease; padding: 4px; }
#menu:hover {max-height: 75%; overflow: auto}
```

The reason I have the 'overflow: auto' when on a smaller screen is due to the entire menu not showing when on a smaller screen - even when I have some elements not showing on mobile screens.

The problem I'm running into is when it DOES overflow and the user scrolls through the menu, when they click/hover out of the menu it retracts like it should but it doesn't show the top of the menu anymore, it will show wherever they scrolled to.

I'd like to find a way either via CSS or Javascript to automatically have that div scroll back to the top when the user clicks/hovers out of the menu so it will still show the menu icon + logo instead of random menu text.

I love how it works but can't stand the scrolling issue on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some awkwardness in your idea that might just need a redesign, I certainly have never noticed a menu working like this.

But the jQuery code to scroll to the top is this:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
```

Where 600 is how long it takes in ms.
You'll have to wrap this in a click() function or something so it triggers when someone presses a menu option.
For example:

```
$('#menu a').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
});
```

And of course all of this code should be wrapped in a $(document).ready() (basic jQuery setup)
I know you didn't mention jQuery in your question, but this is a popular approach to solving problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Yeah, the overflow: auto is kind of awkward. I am not sure how to avoid it, though, if there is too much in the menu. I guess if I really want to avoid it I would just need to re-design the menu to have a completely different one for smaller screens but I was just hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve auto scroll on click using html only.

You just need to add an id to some div (the header maybe) and on the link you pass the #id to the href like so:

html

```
<div id="Header">your header</div>

<a href="#Header">Go to the top</a>
```

css

```
/* Keyword values */
scroll-behavior: auto;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

I'd suggest to try out the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` it makes the transitions, well... smooth :D

Here you can find all the documentation you need about this solution
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior